# Python regular expression, substituting a multiline match not working

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean a text from math formulas. I am using a regex to substitute them but it doesn't seem to work for formulas that span to more than one line.

For example, I have this (dirty) string:

```
tst = """
The appropriate tool to deal in a statistical mechanics framework with a
system of quantum numbers latexmath:[$\vec X=(N,S,Q,C,B)$] is the
canonical partition function (*???*; *???*)
latexmath:[\[Z_{N,S,Q,C,B} = \frac {1}{(2\pi)^5}\int\limits^{\pi}_{-\pi}
d^5\vec\phi\;e^{i\vec\phi\vec X} \exp{(\sum_j z_j)},
\label{eq:partition1}\]] where
latexmath:[\[z_j= g_j\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p\;\ln(1\pm
\exp{(-\sqrt{p^2+m_j^2}/T -i\vec x_j\vec \phi)})^{\pm 1},
\label{eq:partition1b}\]] 
"""
```

This is the regular expression that I have to match the formulas:

```
regex = r"(fm|cm)?latexmath:\[.+?\]\]?"
```

I have also tested it in [regex101](https://regex101.com) and it seems to work.

I use `re.DOTALL` to match multilines. It can replace the formula that does not span between two lines but not the rest. However, when I use `finditer` I see that it also finds the multiline expression.

Here's the result using `re.finditer`. The re.DOTALL flag works here:

```
In [48]: for match in re.finditer(regex, tst):
    ...:     print(repr(match.group(0)))
    ...:     
latexmath:[$\vec X=(N,S,Q,C,B)$]

In [49]: for match in re.finditer(regex, tst, re.DOTALL):
    ...:     print(repr(match.group(0)))
    ...:     
    ...:     
'latexmath:[$\\vec X=(N,S,Q,C,B)$]'
'latexmath:[\\[Z_{N,S,Q,C,B} = \\frac {1}{(2\\pi)^5}\\int\\limits^{\\pi}_{-\\pi}\nd^5\\vec\\phi\\;e^{i\\vec\\phi\\vec X} \\exp{(\\sum_j z_j)},\n\\label{eq:partition1}\\]]'
'latexmath:[\\[z_j= g_j\\frac{V}{(2\\pi)^3}\\int d^3p\\;\\ln(1\\pm\n\\exp{(-\\sqrt{p^2+m_j^2}/T -i\\vec x_j\\vec \\phi)})^{\\pm 1},\n\\label{eq:partition1b}\\]]'
```

However, the same regex does not work with `re.sub` (it only replaces the first occurrence):

```
In [50]: re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst, re.DOTALL)
Out[50]: '\nThe appropriate tool to deal in a statistical mechanics framework with a\nsystem of quantum numbers XXXX is the\ncanonical partition function (*???*; *???*)\nlatexmath:[\\[Z_{N,S,Q,C,B} = \\frac {1}{(2\\pi)^5}\\int\\limits^{\\pi}_{-\\pi}\nd^5\\vec\\phi\\;e^{i\\vec\\phi\\vec X} \\exp{(\\sum_j z_j)},\n\\label{eq:partition1}\\]] where\nlatexmath:[\\[z_j= g_j\\frac{V}{(2\\pi)^3}\\int d^3p\\;\\ln(1\\pm\n\\exp{(-\\sqrt{p^2+m_j^2}/T -i\\vec x_j\\vec \\phi)})^{\\pm 1},\n\\label{eq:partition1b}\\]] '

In [51]: re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst)
Out[51]: '\nThe appropriate tool to deal in a statistical mechanics framework with a\nsystem of quantum numbers XXXX is the\ncanonical partition function (*???*; *???*)\nlatexmath:[\\[Z_{N,S,Q,C,B} = \\frac {1}{(2\\pi)^5}\\int\\limits^{\\pi}_{-\\pi}\nd^5\\vec\\phi\\;e^{i\\vec\\phi\\vec X} \\exp{(\\sum_j z_j)},\n\\label{eq:partition1}\\]] where\nlatexmath:[\\[z_j= g_j\\frac{V}{(2\\pi)^3}\\int d^3p\\;\\ln(1\\pm\n\\exp{(-\\sqrt{p^2+m_j^2}/T -i\\vec x_j\\vec \\phi)})^{\\pm 1},\n\\label{eq:partition1b}\\]] '
```

I'm not sure why `re.sub` is not working with multiline expression here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

[image]

We have

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Then

```
re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst, re.DOTALL)
```

equals to `re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst, count=re.DOTALL)`,so it won't work.

More detail about `re.sub`,see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 1):

try

```
(?s)(?:fm|cm)?latexmath:\[.+?\]\]?
```

just put `re.DOTALL` inside `regex`

> (?iLmsux)
> (One or more letters from the set 'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: re.I (ignore case), re.L (locale dependent), re.M (multi-line), re.S (dot matches all), re.U (Unicode dependent), and re.X (verbose), for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the re.compile() function.
>
> Note that the (?x) flag changes how the expression is parsed. It should be used first in the expression string, or after one or more whitespace characters. If there are non-whitespace characters before the flag, the results are undefined.

or

```
print (re.sub(regex, 'XXXX' , tst, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

see `def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):` ,`S = DOTALL = sre_compile.SRE_FLAG_DOTALL` and  `SRE_FLAG_DOTALL = 16`.